# Polymorphic return type depending on the state of a result

Tags: oop, architecture, return, theory

I've the following method:

```
attemptToGetToken(TokenRequestAttempt attempt);
```

I use a third party component to get the token but it may fail in some case (in the attempt is not valid or missing parameters).

There is no reason to throw an Exception for this case because it is actually expected to fail.

However, depending on the result, the end-user may acts accordingly.

It means I need to return an Object which allows the user to decide what it can/should do.

The probably most obvious answer would be to simply have such class:

```
class AttemptResult {

    constructor(status, token, errorMessage);
    getStatus();
    getToken();
    getErrorMessage();
    isSuccessful();
}
```

And simply return this object properly populated (I may add specific factory method for success/fail state, but it would be just a tool).

The problem I have with this approach is that the contract is not clear.

In the case of failure, the `token` would be `null` but the developper would then have to use the `isSuccessful()` method to check wether or not the attempt succeed.
But nothing will prevent him to call `getToken()` and get a `null` result which may bubble an error somewhere.

So I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to actually return two kind of object.

```
interface TokenAttemptResult {}

class FailedTokenAttempt implements TokenAttemptResult {

   getError();

}

class SuccessfulTokenAttempt implements TokenAttemptResult {

  getToken();
}
```

Because I implement an empty interface to define a relationship between the both result, I may now use this interface as a return type in my service:

```
TokenAttemptResult attemptToGetToken(TokenRequestAttempt attempt);
```

When an user calls the method above, he is in charge to check the return type and act accordingly, it prevents him to call method which should not be supposed to be called and may generate side effects.

What do you think about this kind of design?
Any of you has experimented with it and has any feedbacks?

Please avoid unconstructive answer involving personal preferences without actual arguments, I'm really looking for serious design theories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The subclassing approach will work, however since interfaces are open, the client has no way of being sure that they have exhaustively checked all possible implementing types of the interface. The OO approach to closing the possible cases is the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) e.g.

```
public interface TokenResultVisitor<TResult> {
    TResult Visit(FailedTokenAttempt failure);
    TResult Visit(SuccessfulTokenAttempt success);
}
```

and then

```
interface TokenAttemptResult {
    T Accept<T>(TokenResultVisitor visitor);
}
```

This is a fairly heavyweight approach if you only have two possible cases, so if your language supports first-class functions you can simply define a method which takes two handlers e.g.

```
interface TokenAttemptResult {
    T Handle<T>(success: Result => T, failure: TokenError => T);
}
```

Comment: Good point about the possible implementation! However, I'm wondering if it is acceptable in this case to admit that the Attempt Result may only be a Failure or Success (it speaks by itself). The main goal behind this approach was to properly model the two kind of result possible and avoid runtime error because of accessing an empty token or a ghostly error.